# Tableau: How to calculate a revenue share for a company's product inventory against their competition?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I have been struggling on this problem on Tableau for a while and would really appreciate some help.

For a given company A that has product_id's 1,2,3....,N

How do I calculate their share of revenue for a given product id against other companies B,C,...., N with the same product id?

===========================================================================

My current idea has been to duplicate the data source and then do a simple table calculation:

`SUM([Revenue])/SUM([Duplicate_Data].[Revenue])`

I can then add this calculated measure to the sheet and filter to show the SUM of revenue for company A against all other companies in the duplicate data source. However, this does not aggregate by product id as I would like it to.

Thanks in advance.

Hamza

Comment: Did you mean, for example, Company A for Product 1, Revenue is 100 and Company B for Product 1, Revenue is 400 and Company C for Product 1, Revenue is 800, then it will be [100/SUM(400 + 800)]?

Comment: Yes exactly. I have since created the calculated measure below, which makes sense for me but it is getting the total. revenue for a given product_id wrong:

`{FIXED [Date],[Product_ID]: SUM([Revenue])}`

The above calculation is my attempt at trying to find the sum of revenue for a given product_id in a data range regardless of company. It breaks down when I add the company A to the table though.